# Seeking data for spatial interpolation

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Can someone point me to a Kriging dataset? If it is natural data, it would be very great! (Such as rainfall, porosity, soil density, atmosphere-concentration, etc. ), temperature observations. Or if someone has some dataset they have used for Kriging in the past, could you please share?

Answer (score 1):

[Kriging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging) is a commonly used technique for interpolating point data in GIS.

There are many tutorials for using common GIS software to perform Kriging. Most of these tutorials provide sample data sets. Here are a couple of examples:

- [Tutorial for doing Kriging interpolation in QGIS](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html). The data used in this tutorial is available in two places:

  - http://www.twdb.texas.gov/hydro_survey/Arlington/2007-12/Shapefiles.zip
  - http://www.qgistutorials.com/downloads/Shapefiles.zip
- [This tutorial for ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-surface-using-default-parameters.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_B980C7C8388743D38EED2536A37139CC), like most ArcGIS tutorials, uses datasets that are 
  only available if you have an ArcGIS license. However, ArcGIS tutorials are widely reproduced, so if you search for the name of the dataset mentioned in the tutorial, you can usually find the tutorial data somewhere on teh internets:

  - [Alternate Download Source for the data from the above-linked ArcGIS tutorial (a course assignment from AALTO University)](https://mycourses.aalto.fi/mod/assign/view.php?id=54850)
  - [Direct download link for ca_ozone.gdb](https://mycourses.aalto.fi/pluginfile.php/141790/mod_assign/introattachment/0/ca_ozone.gdb.zip?forcedownload=1)

You can find 10s or 100s more tutorials with accompanying data sets by simply searching for "[QGIS/ ArcGIS/ other GIS software] Kriging tutorial."

Comment: Thanks a lot, From which tutorial was the ozone data ? or do you know its source?

Comment: That data is from the arcgis tutorial I linked to. That tutorial just tells you to get the data from the CD or ArcGIS installation files you already have if you installed ArcGIS, but by searching for the name of the file they mentioned I found it from another website that was guiding people to follow the same tutorial.